# Deno, Fresh framework - html template manipulation

Tags: javascript, deno, preact, freshjs

I was recently playing with new Fresh framework for deno and it was all great but at some point I realized that there is no possibility to add any additional meta data to page head tag. Basically I want to do 2 things:

1. Add title tag
2. Link some css file from my static dir

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?
In the ideal world I would want the possibility to provide my own html template, or at least have some flexible way to manipulate provided fixed template.
I did find some code snippet in Fresh source file which is basically before-mentioned fixed html template, but unfortunately it doesn't look customizable to me - only variable element would be *opts.headComponents*, but I'm unsure if I can affect it.

```js
export interface TemplateOptions {
  bodyHtml: string;
  headComponents: ComponentChildren[];
  imports: (readonly [string, string])[];
  styles: string[];
  preloads: string[];
  lang: string;
}

export function template(opts: TemplateOptions): string {
  const page = (
    <html lang={opts.lang}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        {opts.preloads.map((src) => <link rel="modulepreload" href={src} />)}
        {opts.imports.map(([src, nonce]) => (
          <script src={src} nonce={nonce} type="module"></script>
        ))}
        <style
          id="__FRSH_STYLE"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: opts.styles.join("\n") }}
        />
        {opts.headComponents}
      </head>
      <body dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: opts.bodyHtml }} />
    </html>
  );

  return "<!DOCTYPE html>" + renderToString(page);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer in some [fresh issue](https://github.com/denoland/fresh/issues/379). Edition of head and body tag can be done through JSX, just like this:

```js
/** @jsx h */
import {h} from 'preact';
import {PageProps} from '$fresh/src/server/types.ts';
import {tw} from '@twind';

export const Head = () => (
    <head>
        <title>My title</title>
    </head>
);

export default function LoginPage(props: PageProps) {
    return (
        <div class={tw`w-screen h-screen flex justify-center bg-green-900`}>
            <Head />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Guess that way of doing things comes from preact or SSR? From my point of view it's a bit strange - injecting head/body into some divs, not really intuitive.

**Edit**

Found even better solution, because the answer presented earlier still caused meta tags to be put inside body tag.

We can use *_app.tsx* which is basically a wrapper for each rendered route and use special *Head* component from fresh library. And this is the correct way to populate *opts.headComponents* field from the fixed html template (presented in question). Unfortunately, there seems to be no documentation for that. Example taken from fresh [tests](https://github.com/denoland/fresh/blob/main/tests/fixture/routes/_app.tsx):

```js
/** @jsx h */
/** @jsxFrag Fragment */
import { Fragment, h } from "preact";
import { Head } from "$fresh/runtime.ts";
import { AppProps } from "$fresh/server.ts";

export default function App(props: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="description" content="Hello world!" />
      </Head>
      <props.Component />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: No, it's entirely unrelated to Preact or Preact's render-to-string. This is strictly Fresh/Deno.

Comment: You are asking question in your answer. Please do not add this as an answer, rather edit your question with the information you found and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the `Head` component from fresh and whatever you use as the children will be appended to the `<head>` element of the page you return.

```
// HTML Head to import CSS and fonts
import { Head } from "$fresh/runtime.ts";
```

It's a bad practice to do this on `_app.tsx` because that runs before EVERY request and if you want to have good SEO, you will be setting [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title), [description](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/snippet), and [OG tags](https://ogp.me/) dynamically, which you only know after your request hits the route you are returning data from.

One option that is an excellent middle ground between both options is creating a `DefaultHead` component based on Fresh's `Head`, giving it whatever needs to be added to every request and then accepted as props.children whatever you want to set dynamically.

> /components/DefaultHead.tsx

```
//? HTML Head to import CSS and fonts
import { Head } from "$fresh/runtime.ts";
import { toChildArray } from "preact";
import { JSX } from "preact/jsx-runtime";

//? Define required properties for this Head
interface HeadOptions {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  link?: string;
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

//? Creates and exports the Head to be used on all pages
export function DefaultHead(options: HeadOptions) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{options.title}</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content={options.title} />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content={your-website-name-here} />
        <meta property="og:description" content={options.description} />
        <meta property="description" content={options.description} />
        <meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
        <meta property="og:image" content={/path/to/your-website-image-link-for-social-media-here.png}
        <meta
          property="og:url"
          content={options.link}
        />
        // You can also import here fonts that are used throughout all the website
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/base.css" /> // Default CSS file that has base styles for every page (example: page font-family, background-color, etc)
        {...toChildArray(options.children)} //
      </Head>
    </>
  );
}
```

For ease of use, this code requires importing `toChildArray` so that the props.children is always an array. If you don't want to import this, you will need to manually check it within the `<Head>`, or just make sure you are always either passing a single JSX.Element or an array of them.

Then you can import this `DefaultHead` on every route and dynamically pass in the properties you want to set:

> /routes/literally-any-route.tsx

```
//? Import DefaultHead with default metadata
import { DefaultHead } from "../components/DefaultHead.tsx";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <DefaultHead
        title='page title you want to set'
        description="page description you want to set"
        link="page link you want to show on social media"
      >
        // put here all the elements you want to add to this <DefaultHead>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/page.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/another-page.css" />
      </DefaultHead>
      // everything else for the body of your response goes here...
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the edited answer by [@Harrel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19226764/harrel). However, if you wish to add dynamic content to `<head>` on different pages, like `<title>`, you can use the `<Head>` component in individual pages as well. The children of `<Head>` component will stack because that component is implemented as a context as we can see from the source code

[image]

You can put `<title>` in each page like this

[image]

and meta tags and styleshees in `_app.tsx` like this

[image]

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: _Never_ paste screenshot of code. No one can grab it, no one can test it.

Comment: Sorry, It was not my intention to give code snippets, was only explaining how it worked under the hood.